# Proposal: proper tagging around Sitecore topic

Tags: discussion, tags

The number of [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore)-related threads is approaching 3K, and I thought it is time to have some kind of "rules" around tagging.

This is what I propose:

- all Sitecore-related questions must have [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) tag
- questions related to a specific major version should be tagged `sitecoreX`, where `X` is a major version. For example, [sitecore7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore7)
- questions related to a specific minor version should be tagged `sitecoreX.Y`, where `X` is a major version, `Y` is a minor version. For example, [sitecore7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore7.2)
- minor version tags should be specified in case the behavior is specific to a certain minor version. In this case, the "base" major-version tag should also be provided, for example, [sitecore7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore7)[sitecore7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore7.2)
- all tags related to different Sitecore areas and modules should start from `sitecore-`, for example [sitecore-ecm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-ecm)
- versions of Sitecore modules should NOT be specified with separate tags. The module version should be specified explicitly in the question body, or "calculated" based on the Sitecore major and minor version tags

I can see the following inconsistencies at the moment:

- The base tag [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) is not applied to all Sitecore-related questions
- A tag for TDS (Team Development for Sitecore) is [tds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tds). Should be [sitecore-tds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-tds)
- A tag for Glass Mapper is [glass-mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glass-mapper). This is where I doubt... As far as I can see, Glass Mapper supports Umbraco as well - should the tag be renamed to [sitecore-glass-mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-glass-mapper)?
- A tag for WFFM is [web-forms-for-marketers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-forms-for-marketers). Should be [sitecore-wffm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-wffm)

This is the algorithm to "normalize" a certain tag:

- Find all the questions in that tag, e.g. [speakui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speakui)
- Re-tag each question: remove wrong-named tag ([speakui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speakui)), add properly-named one ([sitecore-speak-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-speak-ui))
- Move (and optionally enhance) the tag wiki to the correct tag

BTW, this is what I've done for the mentioned [sitecore-speak-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-speak-ui) tag as an example. As a result, the unused wrong-named tag is wiped out by StackOverflow automatically.

This will give a number of advantages:

- a person asking a question will find proper tags pretty fast - just type 'sitecore' and choose the one from the dropdown
- a person monitoring Sitecore threads can subscribe to all related tags with a single RSS feed (search for `[sitecore*]`, scroll down the page to find the RSS feed generated link)

What do you think? Good idea? Bad idea? Other alternatives?

Comment: This should be in the Sitecore Tag Wiki (except for the requested tag changes, I guess).

Comment: Your set of bullets about versions is not specific to [sitecore] usage; that's pretty much how tagging is (or at least should be) used for anything on SO.